# Idangerous Swiper with Jquery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, swiper.js

I'm using idangerous swiper for tab kind of option in mobile app. When swiping slide it moves right and left. I'm having image grid inside each slide and applied Jquery Sortable to reorder image.

The problem i'm getting is when dragging image for reordering in slide also makes the move to next or previous slide in the swiper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**noSwiping**](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php)  boolean false (default)/true

> If true, then you can add "noSwipingClass" class to swiper's slide to prevent/disable swiping on this element. New in 2.0.